# Solr Range Facet with Gap +1Day giving wrong results

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

We are firing the following solr query given below. The facet results are giving all the data is present for the 12th. But that's in-correct as data is divided by between 12th and 13th, as it's displayed in the same query with GAP=+1HOUR. How can we fix this discrepancy,

**QUERY WITH DATE GAP=+1DAY**

```
{
 "responseHeader":{
"zkConnected":true,
"status":0,
"QTime":929,
"params":{
  "facet.range":"createdOnGMTDate",
  "q":"QUERY COMES HERE",
  "facet.range.gap":"+1DAY",
  "fq":["createdOnGMTDate:[2020-03-12T12:30:00Z TO 2020-03-13T12:30:59Z]",
    "-msgprops:(\"33272~D\")"],
  "rows":"0",
  "facet":"true",
  "facet.range.start":"2020-03-12T18:00:00Z-330MINUTES",
  "facet.range.end":"2020-03-13T18:00:59Z-330MINUTES"}},
  "response":{"numFound":165,"start":0,"maxScore":73.9708,"docs":[]
  },
 "facet_counts":{
"facet_queries":{},
"facet_fields":{},
"facet_ranges":{
  "createdOnGMTDate":{
    "counts":[
      "2020-03-12T12:30:00Z",165,
      "2020-03-13T12:30:00Z",0],
    "gap":"+1DAY",
    "start":"2020-03-12T12:30:00Z",
    "end":"2020-03-14T12:30:00Z"}},
"facet_intervals":{},
"facet_heatmaps":{}}}
```

**QUERY WITH DATE GAP=+1HOUR**

```
{
 "responseHeader":{
 "zkConnected":true,
 "status":0,
 "QTime":1483,
 "params":{
  "facet.range":"createdOnGMTDate",
  "q":"QUERY COMES HERE ",
  "facet.range.gap":"+1HOUR",
  "fq":["createdOnGMTDate:[2020-03-12T12:30:00Z TO 2020-03-13T12:30:59Z]",
    "-msgprops:(\"33272~D\")"],
  "rows":"0",
  "facet":"true",
  "facet.range.start":"2020-03-12T18:00:00Z-330MINUTES",
  "facet.range.end":"2020-03-13T18:00:59Z-330MINUTES"}},
  "response":{"numFound":165,"start":0,"maxScore":73.9687,"docs":[]
  },
 "facet_counts":{
 "facet_queries":{},
"facet_fields":{},
"facet_ranges":{
  "createdOnGMTDate":{
    "counts":[
      "2020-03-12T12:30:00Z",25,
      "2020-03-12T13:30:00Z",12,
      "2020-03-12T14:30:00Z",28,
      "2020-03-12T15:30:00Z",22,
      "2020-03-12T16:30:00Z",24,
      "2020-03-12T17:30:00Z",5,
      "2020-03-12T18:30:00Z",11,
      "2020-03-12T19:30:00Z",8,
      "2020-03-12T20:30:00Z",3,
      "2020-03-12T21:30:00Z",4,
      "2020-03-12T22:30:00Z",2,
      "2020-03-12T23:30:00Z",1,
      "2020-03-13T00:30:00Z",1,
      "2020-03-13T01:30:00Z",2,
      "2020-03-13T02:30:00Z",2,
      "2020-03-13T03:30:00Z",5,
      "2020-03-13T04:30:00Z",5,
      "2020-03-13T05:30:00Z",2,
      "2020-03-13T06:30:00Z",1,
      "2020-03-13T07:30:00Z",0,
      "2020-03-13T08:30:00Z",1,
      "2020-03-13T09:30:00Z",0,
      "2020-03-13T10:30:00Z",1,
      "2020-03-13T11:30:00Z",0,
      "2020-03-13T12:30:00Z",0],
    "gap":"+1HOUR",
    "start":"2020-03-12T12:30:00Z",
    "end":"2020-03-13T13:30:00Z"}},
"facet_intervals":{},
"facet_heatmaps":{}}}
```

What are we missing?

Comment: Did you try `facet.range.start":"2020-03-12T00:00:00Z` instead of `facet.range.start":"2020-03-12T18:00:00Z-330MINUTES`? Since you already have a `fq` to filter your dates, it should work. Try resetting the time to 00 hours for both facet.range.start and end

Comment: The -330MINUTES is to adjust timezone instead of using TZ parameter. Removing that wouldn't give the right results.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect - from your example there is no data that is present after `2020-03-13T12:30:00Z` (where the second interval starts - i.e. `<start> + 1DAY`)? The grouping isn't rounded to the date - it's `<previous start time> + 1 day` for each group. If you want the group to start at midnight, use midnight as the starting point (and use the `fq` to cut off those documents you don't want included.). You can use `/DAY` on the start date to round it off to just the date part if necessary.